# How do you test android APK files on Galaxy S5?

Tags: galaxy, usb-debugging, s5

I was trying to install an APK file generated by an android build. I was using Galaxy S5. I plugged the phone in via USB to my computer but adb was unable to detect the device.

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
```

What do I do to make this phone visible to adb? The reason why I want to use adb is this is how you install android apps onto devices. In the past you just had to select the option to enable usb debugging but in recent version of android this feature is not readily available.

Comment: I don't think it was appropriate to close this ticket as off-topic given the popularity of this question among developers of android. I just earned the popular question badge for this question.

Comment: I also have another step to the solution for this, which I would love to post as an answer if we could reopen. You need to download the Samsung USB driver: http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117

Comment: Actually, this would have been a better question for [android.se] than Super User. Not sure why it was nominated for reopening, though. It's definitely off-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution finally.

1. Go to the settings menu on your GS5.
2. Scroll down to the "System section and tap "About Device."
3. Now scroll down to "Build number."
4. Tap the "Build number" section seven times. (You'll see a warning that you're about to unlock developer options.)
5. Now back out to the main settings menu, and under "SYSTEM" you'll see "Developer options" listed.
6. Under Developer options you select USB debugging
7. Now run `adb devices` in the command line and the phone will be visible

Comment: Wow, why didn't I think of that - Konami code to access a setting, intuitive! Anyway, thanks for answer - saved us a buncha time :)